# Error handling of input arguments of the function

Tags: python, python-2.7

My main code has 4 input parameters. I created a parsing function that checks input parameters.

What is a correct way to handle errors? I want to check if the user specified all 4 parameters (not 2 or 3 or whatever), `p4` is boolean and `p1`-`p3` are string values.

```
def parse_parameters():
    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "d")
       p1, p2, p3, p4 = args
       return p1, p2, p3, p4
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
       print "Wrong usage"
       sys.exit(1)
```

UPDATE:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     p1, p2, p3, p4 = parse_parameters()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ***argparse*** instead and set option `required=True`, this way you don't need to handle those conditions. This module will do it for you.

**Ex**:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.foo)
```

**usage:**

> argparse.py [-h] [--foo FOO]
>
> argparse.py: error: option --foo is required

[Further Reading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required)

Comment: How can I specify that `--foo` should be assigned to the variable `foo` to be able to use it in the code?

Comment: Do check the code now, and go through documentation for further options that you can pass

Comment: So, I should put your code into `try` and add `except`, right?

Comment: Yea you can do that